# How to add red/green wire on belt without stopping it?

Tags: factorio

I was adding green wires in order to have my factory monitor the amount of resources in the system. However when I placed a green wire on a conveyor belt, the belt stopped.

I had to manually set it to "Read contents" instead of "Enable/disable" mode. This stopping hindered my factory progress. How can I place the wire without stopping the belt?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the copy and paste feature. First, make an extra unused belt somewhere else. Place red/green wire on it and configure it as you wish.

After that, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and Right click the belt. All settings were copied.

You can now <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Left click any belt and the settings will be pasted on it - even if it doesn't have any wires attached. Once you attach red/green wire, the pasted settings will take effect immediately.

The only downside is that it's impossible to see what the settings are (and whether you pasted them successfully) before attaching the belt.